# How to fix 401 Unauthorized in the response of the authentication login

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I have problem regarding to this 401 Unauthorized when I submit the form in the reactjs, however when I use the postman it gives me token, so what should I need to change in my function to make successfully authorized my credential.

I will show you guys my code in my function.

```
submitLogin(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    let bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.set('email',this.state.email);
    bodyFormData.set('password', this.state.password);

    axios({
        method:'post',
        url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login',
        data:bodyFormData,
        body: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept':'application/json' }}

    }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(function (response){
        console.log(response);
    })


}
```

**In my web:**

[image: Output]

**In my postman:**

[image: Output]

**My payload:**

[image: payload]

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass headers in the body. Also when using `FormData` you don't need to specify the content type. Axios does sort that out

Comment: Can you show the DevTools details for that request? Specifically the "Form Data" at the end.

Comment: @apokryfos what do you mean for this?

Comment: @Thomas ok i will show you

Comment: Line that says `body: { headers:..` can be removed as it doesn't actually do anything

Comment: @Thomas see the payload

Comment: The names that are submitted are wrong (`inpUser` instead of `email`). Are you sure you posted the correct code?

Comment: Your login form probably has the wrong `name` properties associated with the inputs.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Authorization header:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${access_token}`
```

And remove headers from the request body;

Comment: There is no access token yet when submitting a login form.